# Delete stores massively on Store Locator

Tags: stores

I need to delete all the stores from Store Locator but when I asked development team, they told me this can be done only manually.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the Store Locator module you are using, some modules support mass delete stores, and some do not. You can check that in the Store Locator grid in admin > Select all > Click Action.

If your store locator module doesn't have Mass delete action, and your site has a huge amount of store locator items, you can ask the developer team to delete all stores locators item by code.